# Restore `numpy.random.seed` accidentally overwritten in interactive session

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I was in the middle of a reasonably complicated interactive python session, and I had a lot of state that I didn't want to have to regenerate.  (Normally I wouldn't be doing that -- it's pretty stupid -- but sometimes...)

Instead of `numpy.random.seed(42)` I typed by accident `numpy.random.seed = 42` thus making the `numpy.random.seed()` function unreachable.

I hoped that `import numpy` might fix it, but it didn't.

I'm curious to know if there is a general method for recovering from this kind of daft mistake?  Or even a specific one?

Comment: Bet that was a stressful few minutes . . .

Answer (score 2):

First you need to load the `importlib` library, and then tell it to reload `numpy.random`.

```
import importlib
importlib.reload(numpy.random)
```

Note that it's not enough to reload `numpy` itself, since that will just do an ordinary `import` on  `random`, and finding it already there won't make any difference.

But you're right -- you should try to avoid getting into a situation like this with complicated state.